# Selenium Webdriver - How to close popup window with java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to automate the page : https://webp.caixa.gov.br/urbanizacao/siurbn/acompanhamento/ac_publico/sistema/asp/ptei_filtro_inicial.asp

When i type any number on the left box where it says "Informe o Número da Operação"

http://s2.postimg.org/9q65c04qh/Screen_Shot_2014_10_30_at_9_45_57_PM.png

and then click on the right box. It popups a window.. and i am not able to close it. How can i do it?

http://s9.postimg.org/e6tjusgcv/Screen_Shot_2014_10_30_at_9_46_22_PM.png

please help me with this..

Comment: post some of your code to get better help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```